# Focus / Blur IE vs chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, focus, blur

Hello I came across this problem and was wondering if anybody had a fix for it.

```js
function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("two").focus();
}
function blur2() {
  let focus = 
 document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
 };
```

```css
#two{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.inside{
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Click</button>
<div id="two" tabindex="1" onblur = "blur2()">
<div class="inside">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

In chrome, whenever you click on the yellow or Hello World, the `div #two` does not lose focus. 
 However, in IE, the `div #two` does not loose focus if you click on the yellow, **but** blurs if the Hello World is clicked.

I would obviously like to have the chrome behavior in all browser.

Thanks

Comment: Is it specific to any `IE` version?

Comment: I only tested in IE 11

Comment: I'm having similar problems in IE.. will answer if I manage to fix this..